# How to find X numbers in text wrangler

Tags: textwrangler

i have a text file that looks like this:

```
word1[53]
word2[14]
word3[99]
```

what expression to i need to use in my find/replace to find any two numbers like the ones above?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Textwrangler uses ordinary [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) when the "Grep" option is selected in the search dialog, so any basic tutorial on regular expressions will tell you what you need to know.

As it stands, your question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by "any two numbers"? If you want something that will match **word***x***[***y***]**, where *x* is any single digit and *y* is any pair of digits, then this pattern will work:

```
word\d\[\d\d\]
```

By way of explanation, `\d` is a pattern that matches any single digit (0–9). You also need to escape the `[` and `]` characters with backslashes because these characters have special significance in regular expressions when unescaped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked when I escaped the brackets and used \d in grep mode.

Comment: @squeamish, Do they use grep-regex or normal regex?

Comment: @Pacerier It seems to support Perl-like regular expressions.